# Docker + Wordpress - get this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()"

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I am using Docker to run my old Wordpress project. After migrating on Docker i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
/var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:1570 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php(658): wpdb->db_connect() 
#1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php(404): wpdb->__construct('wordpress_user', 'secret', 'wordpress_acade...', 'academy-mysql:3...') 
#2 /var/www/html/wp-settings.php(106): require_wp_db() 
#3 /var/www/html/wp-config.php(122): require_once('/var/www/html/w...') 
#4 /var/www/html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/var/www/html/w...') 
#5 /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/var/www/html/w...') 
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require('/var/www/html/w...') 
#7 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1570
```

I tried following things:
 - add MySQL extensions to Dockerfile
 - remove plugins
 - change theme
But without success.

Comment: can show your docker file?

Comment: Here is my Dockerfile for web server

https://ufile.io/d0sf9

Comment: Why are you not using the official wordpress image? https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/, Why reinvent the wheel

Comment: change to PHP 5.6.* instead of PHP 7.1(mysql extension already removed) and add mysql to this line "RUN docker-php-ext-install zip pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mcrypt intl mysql" because your wordpress still using mysql which's deprecated already.

Comment: Now on step 10 i get this error:

Step 10/30 : RUN a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Running in a265fab16dbb
/bin/sh: 1: a2enmod: not found
ERROR: Service 'web-server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c a2enmod rewrite' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: Even if i use mysqli function get Fatal error

Answer (score 34):

Make sure you have the mysqli extension installed.
If not, for the php container in dockerfile add this installation instruction:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Comment: this did it for me. Not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: for me too! Thanks!

Comment: didnt worked for me, also added `extension=php.mysql.so` to php.ini file, still same error. using mysql8, php8, wordpress 5.9 and docker

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `php:7.4.33-apache` in docker-compose.yml and keep getting the same error.

I just changed it to the following Dockerfile and it worked:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.33-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```